# How to debug "com.android.okhttp"

Tags: java, android, dalvik

In android kitkat, URLConnection's implementation has been replaced by OkHttp,How can it debug it?

The OkHttp is in this directory:`external/okhttp/android/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp`

When i call the `UrlInstance.openConnection().getClass().getName()`, it present `com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl`

How can i debug the it ? It seems that i can't associate the `/android/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/*` to the `com.android.okhttp.*`

When the code excute to the  `return streamHandler.openConnection(this);`

```
/**
 * Returns a new connection to the resource referred to by this URL.
 *
 * @throws IOException if an error occurs while opening the connection.
 */
public URLConnection openConnection() throws IOException {
    return streamHandler.openConnection(this);
}
```

Go forward further,but can't dig into the `com.squareup.okhttp.HttpHandler#openConnection`

The The highlighted thread in debugger in the picture below is gray.

```
package com.squareup.okhttp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;

public class HttpHandler extends URLStreamHandler {
    @Override protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        return newOkHttpClient(null /* proxy */).open(url);
    }

    @Override protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url, Proxy proxy) throws IOException {
        if (url == null || proxy == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("url == null || proxy == null");
        }
        return newOkHttpClient(proxy).open(url);
    }

    @Override protected int getDefaultPort() {
        return 80;
    }

    protected OkHttpClient newOkHttpClient(Proxy proxy) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setFollowProtocolRedirects(false);
        if (proxy != null) {
            client.setProxy(proxy);
        }

        return client;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Foxinsocks the OkHttp is  in AOSP sources `external/okhttp/android/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp` ,but,the runtime class is`com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl`. I want follow the code step by step , but now ,i'm unable

Comment: @Foxinsocks i want follow the code execution. But, i don't know how to assoiate the OkHttp sources to `com.android.okhttp`

Comment: do you have a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

It seems from version 0.8.x onwards of Android Studio the option to attach specific sources at the Android SDK has been removed (Read comments here https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts/GNcGL6xVth1).

I guess if you want to debug you could try an older version or Android Studio, or (and I'd go with this solution) export a portion of your application to Eclipse (the Android SDK version), maybe just the part involving the troublesome connection, and there you can attach sources for a class that has no sources attached during debug very easily, you should see a page with just the signatures of the methods in the Source Code View, with the button to "Attach source"

[image: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-a2EnbC4wP6g/UN2Z7QzFlyI/AAAAAAAAAg0/D2tFh6AgRrM/s1600/Eclipse_String_Class_File.PNG]