# Does Android use OkHttp internally?

Tags: android, android-source, okhttp

This is a stack trace I get when running an Android app I recently inherited. We're not using *OkHttp* as an explicitly dependency, and the `com.android.okhttp` in the trace makes me think the *AOSP* is using *OkHttp* now internally?

```
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
E      at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
E      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:278)
E      at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
E      at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
E      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
E      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
E      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
E      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
E      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
E      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:143)
E      at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldInt(URLConnection.java:544)
E      at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:316)
E      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:182)
```

Comment: In Android KitKat, yea.
source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168450/how-to-debug-com-android-okhttp

Comment: This had me in knots trying to figure out the source of the dependency.

Answer (score 45):

Yes, Android [as of Android 4.4](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/482563299511250944) is using OkHttp for its internal `HttpUrlConnection` implementation.

Comment: What was used before that?

Comment: @ddog: Stuff from [Apache Harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Harmony), most likely.

Comment: It's an older fork. So OkHttp 4.9.1 in your app doesn't impact the HttpUrlConnection.