# App crashes with facebook sdk

Tags: java, android, facebook

My app crashes occasionally with no crash log within my app's logcat. But I found the following log in the system log:

```
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113] Throwing new exception 'Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Transport.writeRequestHeaders(com.android.okhttp.Request)' on a null object reference' 
                                    with unexpected pending exception: java.io.IOException: Hostname 'graph.facebook.com' was not verified
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at void com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(com.android.okhttp.TunnelRequest) (Connection.java:201)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at void com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(int, int, com.android.okhttp.TunnelRequest) (Connection.java:151)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(com.android.okhttp.Request) (HttpEngine.java:277)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest() (HttpEngine.java:215)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at boolean com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(boolean) (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:374)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse() (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at int com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode() (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at int com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode() (DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at int com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode() (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Response.fromHttpConnection(java.net.HttpURLConnection, com.facebook.RequestBatch) (Response.java:312)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Request.executeConnectionAndWait(java.net.HttpURLConnection, com.facebook.RequestBatch) (Request.java:1561)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(com.facebook.RequestBatch) (Request.java:1460)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(java.util.Collection) (Request.java:1429)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(com.facebook.Request[]) (Request.java:1411)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at com.facebook.Response com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait(com.facebook.Request) (Request.java:1383)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at com.facebook.Response com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait() (Request.java:1269)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at com.facebook.model.GraphObject com.facebook.internal.Utility.getAppSettingsQueryResponse(java.lang.String) (Utility.java:708)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at com.facebook.model.GraphObject com.facebook.internal.Utility.access$000(java.lang.String) (Utility.java:57)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at com.facebook.model.GraphObject com.facebook.internal.Utility$1.doInBackground(java.lang.Void[]) (Utility.java:630)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at java.lang.Object com.facebook.internal.Utility$1.doInBackground(java.lang.Object[]) (Utility.java:627)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at java.lang.Object android.os.AsyncTask$2.call() (AsyncTask.java:288)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:237)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at void android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run() (AsyncTask.java:233)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/thread.cc:1113]   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:820)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284] Runtime aborting...
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284] Aborting thread:
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284] "AsyncTask #2" prio=4 tid=53 Runnable
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=1 obj=0x12c00bc0 self=0x9bf2b800
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | sysTid=8392 nice=10 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xa1870d00
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | state=R schedstat=( 46911510 369718290 163 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | stack=0x97886000-0x97888000 stackSize=1036KB
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #00 pc 00004c58  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #01 pc 000034c1  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #02 pc 002526ad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #03 pc 0023618b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+162)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #04 pc 00225b79  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*)+32)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #05 pc 00225de3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+354)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #06 pc 00225fdb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+82)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #07 pc 000a72e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1360)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #08 pc 002340e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::AssertNoPendingExceptionForNewException(char const*) const+406)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #09 pc 00237ead  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowNewException(art::ThrowLocation const&, char const*, char const*)+24)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #10 pc 000690db  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThrowException(art::ThrowLocation const*, char const*, art::mirror::Class*, char const*, std::__va_list*)+306)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #11 pc 00069567  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThrowNullPointerExceptionForMethodAccessImpl(art::ThrowLocation const&, unsigned int, art::DexFile const&, art::InvokeType)+254)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #12 pc 00069785  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThrowNullPointerExceptionFromDexPC(art::ThrowLocation const&)+372)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #13 pc 002914c1  /system/lib/libart.so (artThrowNullPointerExceptionFromCode+108)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #14 pc 00340355  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_com_android_okhttp_internal_http_HttpEngine_readResponse__+412)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:599)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.Response.fromHttpConnection(Response.java:312)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.Request.executeConnectionAndWait(Request.java:1561)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1460)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1429)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1411)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait(Request.java:1383)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait(Request.java:1269)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getAppSettingsQueryResponse(Utility.java:708)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.internal.Utility.access$000(Utility.java:57)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.internal.Utility$1.doInBackground(Utility.java:630)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.internal.Utility$1.doInBackground(Utility.java:627)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:233)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:820)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284] Pending exception java.io.IOException thrown by 'boolean com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(boolean):392'
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284] java.io.IOException: Hostname 'graph.facebook.com' was not verified
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at void com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(com.android.okhttp.TunnelRequest) (Connection.java:201)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at void com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(int, int, com.android.okhttp.TunnelRequest) (Connection.java:151)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(com.android.okhttp.Request) (HttpEngine.java:277)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest() (HttpEngine.java:215)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at boolean com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(boolean) (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:374)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse() (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at int com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode() (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at int com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode() (DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at int com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode() (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Response.fromHttpConnection(java.net.HttpURLConnection, com.facebook.RequestBatch) (Response.java:312)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Request.executeConnectionAndWait(java.net.HttpURLConnection, com.facebook.RequestBatch) (Request.java:1561)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(com.facebook.RequestBatch) (Request.java:1460)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(java.util.Collection) (Request.java:1429)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.util.List com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(com.facebook.Request[]) (Request.java:1411)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.Response com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait(com.facebook.Request) (Request.java:1383)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.Response com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait() (Request.java:1269)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.model.GraphObject com.facebook.internal.Utility.getAppSettingsQueryResponse(java.lang.String) (Utility.java:708)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.model.GraphObject com.facebook.internal.Utility.access$000(java.lang.String) (Utility.java:57)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at com.facebook.model.GraphObject com.facebook.internal.Utility$1.doInBackground(java.lang.Void[]) (Utility.java:630)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.lang.Object com.facebook.internal.Utility$1.doInBackground(java.lang.Object[]) (Utility.java:627)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at java.lang.Object android.os.AsyncTask$2.call() (AsyncTask.java:288)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:237)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at void android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run() (AsyncTask.java:233)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:820)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:284] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock
```

And something about the environment:

```
Compile Sdk Version: 21
Build Tools Version: "21.0.2"
Android version: 5.0.1
Facebook sdk version: 3.20.0
```

This question says android uses okhttp internally from kitkat [Does Android use OkHttp internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000027/does-android-use-okhttp-internally)

Comment: Please post your source code that shows where you are making the http request.

Comment: Actually I have not call any code about Facebook yet.